# How to open external URL in new window from angular js and control newly opened window from controller

Tags: angularjs

Is there a way to open external URL in new window and keep an watch over URL change in newly open window and take actions accordingly. And i want to get cookies values also from newly open window.Basically I'm developing website in angularjs. To signup or login i'm using social media. For example on clicking facebook button(using passportjs for social login ) it should redirect user to facebook login screen and once login is successful user will be redirected to a page where i'll be sending access and refresh token in cookies from my server once redirect is done. So i want to keep watch over URL and redirect user to profile page once redirecting is done and want to fetch value from cookies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

new window -> no rootScope or any other scope.
You don't have the same "runtine environment" cross windows

You can't control a new window with the one that open it.

You have to "boot" another angualr and passing parameters, if needed in another way.

**UPDATE**

normally with 3th party authentication you can choose the page that you want to land.

For angularjs I found the lib [satellizer](https://github.com/sahat/satellizer) that is pretty good and give you support for all the principal identity provider(facebook, twitter, guthub ecc).

Take a look and tell me if is what are you searching

Comment: Is it possible to do in same window??

Comment: It would be helpful if you can give some example.

Comment: Need some more info. What kind of content on the new window(third party? sour code?). Edit the question with some more info and we can elaborate something

Comment: Thank You very much. :). I'll get back to you if i get some problem.Thanks alot!!

Comment: Hii Rick, need your help. so now using satellizer what i want to use my own server api for social login. For example in my server http://localhost/auth/facebook will redirect you to facebook login page and once login gets over it will redirect you to other url(localhost/socialLogin/done) and you will get cookies on this page. so i want to read this cookies and want to close popup window. So please can you help to modify satellizer library for this?

Comment: not sure to understand all. Why you want to proxy the call between the app and facebook? at this point it isn't better to do all the auth on th eback end and recevie the cookie?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111644/discussion-between-krunal-and-rick).